# ios Swift tableView dynamic cells constraints for labels and image programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have labels and an image. I want labels above image. And image without leading and trailing margin constraints.

I have tried the following constraints but can't seem to get it right. And the row height for the cells doesn't adjust accordingly in landscape mode.

```
    addSubview(videolabel1)
    videolabel1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    videolabel1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    videolabel1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor
        , constant: 20).isActive  = true

    videolabel1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    videolabel1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true


    addSubview(image)
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive  = true
    image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoimage.heightAnchor
        , multiplier: 16/9).isActive = true

    image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videodate.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
```

Comment: add screenshot of result you got.It is easy to find mistakes

Comment: You can achieve it by using nested stackviews and adding arranged subviews. Also, please add screenshots of your current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `UIStackView`'s when you want to arrange views in a horizontal or vertical fashion. The `UIStackView` can take care of most constraints for you.
You can try adding a parent `UIStackView` with vertical orientation, that contains another `UIStackView` with horizontal orientation (this `UIStackView` will contain two `UILabel's`), followed by the `UIImageView`, and another `UILabel`.

```
parentStackView = UIStackView()
parentStackView.axis = .vertical
parentStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
parentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.contentView.addSubview(parentStackView)
parentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
parentStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
parentStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

parentStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
parentStackView.addArrangedSubview(stackView)
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
stackView.spacing = 10
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
label.text = "First Label";
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label2)
label2.text = "Second Label";
parentStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView);
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageview");
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) ]);
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = true;
parentStackView.addArrangedSubview(label3)
label3.text = "Vertical Label below Image";
```

The result will look something like:

[image]

Comment: Try removing layout margins on parentStackView, this should match the width of all its immediate children, including the image with that of the cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more on the 2:1 part. Also, meanwhile you can try fixing the height of imageView and setting the contentMode on imageView to scaleAspectFill.

Comment: You can set the height of imageView to (width of screen)/2, perhaps? Something like NSLayoutConstraint.activate([imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) ]) along with the contentMode.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set bottom and top anchor according to sequential view on top and bottom. Here, you are setting bottom anchor of both videolabel1 and videodate to bottom anchor which is wrong:-

**set videoLabel trailing and top anchor and remove bottom anchor:-**

```
videolabel1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive  = true
videolabel1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

**set videoLabel trailing anchor as below and remove bottom anchor:-**

```
videodate.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive  = true
```

**Also, remove bottom anchor of imagview and set bottom anchor constant as shown below:-**

```
videotitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
```